# Trying to hide nav menu only at certain width and scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

I'm currently working on this site http://paramountwell.staging.wpengine.com/. When the scroll is greater than 250 down or when the window width is less than 1105px, the nav changes to a button, that has the menu appear. Which is all fine and working as expected.

I also have it set up so that if the scroll is less than 250 it hides the responsive menu if the button is active, so you can use the main nav bar.

The problem is that with the scroll is less than 250 and the window is less than 1105px, and you push the button the menu won't appear because its supposed to be hidden at less than 250 scroll.

So basically I need to code in jQuery, **"if the scroll is less than 250 and the window width is greater than 1105 hide the menu"**

What is the best way to do this in jQuery?

Here is the site link again.
http://paramountwell.staging.wpengine.com/

edit: 
I almost have this

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll <= 250 && windowWidth >= 1105) {
        header.removeClass('header-scroll');
        navToggleMenu.addClass('hide-scroll_menu');
    } else {
        header.addClass('header-scroll');
        navToggleMenu.removeClass('hide-scroll_menu');
    }
});
```

EDIT -- Basically I need to set it up so that it will **ONLY** remove 'header-scroll' and add 'hide-scroll-menu' when the scroll is less than 250 and the window width is greater than 1105.

Right now it doesn't work if the window is less than 1105 and the scroll is less than 250. Every where else it works perfectly.

Comment: please share the relevant code here

Comment: Do you know how to get the scrolled pixels? Do you know how to get the window's width?

Comment: I do, I figured it out. I was just way over thinking it. Thanks, for reading sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: Unrelated to the question my unsolicited personal opinion on the design, in the hope of you maybe finding it useful here or there: The hover effects on the four major buttons are a tad to slow. Hover color grey on blue/red looks unprofessional to me (bad contrast), corner radius above 2px looks outdated. The buttons under "Well Service and Repair" lack a hover effect. For a comparison of the current with the improved look, see here: https://ibb.co/haLs65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on('addRemoveClass', function(e, scroll, windowW){
   if (scroll <= 250 && windowW >= 1105) {
       header.removeClass('header-scroll');
       navToggleMenu.addClass('hide-scroll_menu');
   } else {
       header.addClass('header-scroll');
       navToggleMenu.removeClass('hide-scroll_menu');
   }
});
$(window).resize(function() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   var windowW = $(window).width();
   $('body').trigger('addRemoveClass', [scroll, windowW]);
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   var windowW = $(window).width();
   $('body').trigger('addRemoveClass', [scroll, windowW]);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank You! Window Resize Function, duh! Thank you.